# How can i overpower autosize in TextView?

Tags: java, android

I have a large text to be displayed. But i append text on swipes. Swipe left for another line of text. Swipe right for cleaning up TextView. 
As my text is really long i decidede to add autosize to it but there is a problem. I want my text size to be back to default on swipe right.

I tried adding setTextSize method inside of Listener

```
    swipeableView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(CardsScrollActivity.this) {
            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                fade.reset();
                questionView.clearAnimation();
                questionView.startAnimation(fade);
                tipsView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
                tipsView.setText("");
                sb.delete(0, sb.length());
                i[0] = 0;
                finalCycler.setNextCard();
                questionView.setText(finalCycler.currentCard.getQuestion());
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                if (finalCycler.currentCard.getTips().length > i[0]) {
                    sb.append("\t\t");
                    sb.append(finalCycler.currentCard.getTips()[i[0]]).append('\n');
                    tipsView.setText(sb.toString());
                    i[0]++;
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No more tips", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tips"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="5sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
```

I would like text size to be 20sp after swiping right. But it appears to be last value of autosize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to disable the autosizing feature when you don't want it using the command `setAutoSizeTextTypeWithDefaults(int autoSizeTextType)` and provide it the value `AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_NONE`. When you want to re-enable it, you would provide the same function with the value `AUTO_SIZE_TEXT_TYPE_UNIFORM` to "scale the horizontal and the vertical axes uniformly". A full explanation is on [Android's developer site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview).

Comment: Is there anyway i can do that with lower level api?

Comment: figured it out.
Thanks